# Change deeply nested property on object, but with arrays mixed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the `title` and `description` properties on an individual task without mutating the state. The nesting is complex

```
dayColumns: [
          {
            id: 'monday',
            tasks: [{
                  key: cellTime,
                  dayOfWeek: columnDay,
                  date: date,
                  timeStart: cellTime,
                  timeEnd: cellTime + blockInterval * 60000,
                  initalBlockSize: blockInterval,
                  title: '',
                  description: '',
                }, 
                {
                  key: cellTime,
                  dayOfWeek: columnDay,
                  date: date,
                  timeStart: cellTime,
                  timeEnd: cellTime + blockInterval * 60000,
                  initalBlockSize: blockInterval,
                  title: '',
                  description: '',
                }],
          },
          {
            id: 'tuesday',
            tasks: [],
          },
          {
            id: 'wednesday',
            tasks: [],
          },
          {
            id: 'thursday',
            tasks: [],
          },
          {
            id: 'friday',
            tasks: [],
          },
          {
            id: 'saturday',
            tasks: [],
          },
          {
            id: 'sunday',
            tasks: [],
          },
        ];
```

This is the function I have so far. I have adjusted this many times and I think my errors are with the returns.

```
case SET_TASK_TEXT:
      const { textType, newText, key, dayOfWeek } = action.payload;
      const newTextDayColumns = state.dayColumns.map((column) => {
        if (column.id === dayOfWeek) {
          const newTasks = column.tasks.map(
            (task) => {
              if (task.key === key && textType === 'title') {
                return { ...task, title: newText };
              }
              if (task.key === key && textType === 'description') {
                return { ...task, description: newText };
              }
            }
            /** Change title or description according to @param textType */
          );
          return [...column.tasks, newTasks];
        }
        return {...state.dayColumns, newTextDayColumns}
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        dayColumns: newTextDayColumns,
      };
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I've create separate actions like change title and change description

Comment: Take a look at lenses. Ramda.js has an implementation of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your last `{...state.dayColumns, newTextDayColumns}` is wrong, you should only return the same column or a new one with updated tasks. Also, you should not return `[...column.tasks, newTasks]` from your map.

```
const newTextDayColumns = state.dayColumns.map((column) => {
  // return column if no match
  if (column.id !== dayOfWeek) return column;

  const newTasks = column.tasks.map(
    (task) => {
      if (task.key === key && textType === 'title') {
        return { ...task, title: newText };
      }
      if (task.key === key && textType === 'description') {
        return { ...task, description: newText };
      }
      // it's good to return task if conditionals above fail
      return task;
    }
  );
  // return new column with updated task
  return {...column, tasks: newTasks};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator almost always mutates your current state since while using it with an array, you are taking all its individual elements and creating a new array to place then into.

Same goes for objects.

Although this can be done in a slightly better way it would still result in such enormous, confusing and hard to maintain code.

[Immutability Helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutability-helper) package solves this exact problem by simplifying the way you update states.